# can't find symbol crypto_stream_salsa20_xor_ic in libsodium.so.4

Tags: shadow

I get

```
can't find symbol crypto_stream_salsa20_xor_ic in libsodium.so.4
```

when starting `shadowsocks` with `chacha20` mode. How to use `chacha20` on `shadowsocks`?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your libsodium to the lastest version.Such as:

```
//if you has install libsodium by `yum`,you should remove it first.
wget https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases/download/1.0.10/libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz
tar zxvf libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz
cd libsodium-1.0.10
./configure && make && make install
echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr_local_lib.conf
ldconfig
```

Everything is fine now.